# Regex: Replace the content of a tag with the content of another tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this tags, and I want to replace the content of a tag (link-one) with the content of another tag (link two). So, to extract the content of a tag and replace it in another tag. For example

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com/link-one.html" />`

`<a href="/en/link-two.html">`

The output should be:

`<link rel="canonical" href="https:/mywebsite.com/link-two.html" />`

I made a regex, that almost works, but it must be a little bit improved..

**Search:**

`(<link rel="canonical" href=").*?(" \/>)(.*?)(<a href="/en/(.*?)">)`

**Replace by:**

`\1\5\3\4`

(check `.Matches newline`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com/\K.*?(?=" />.+?<a href="/en/(.*?)">)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com/
\K                  # forget all we have seen  until this position
.*?                 # 0 or more any character, not greedy
(?=                 # positive lookahead
  " />              # literally
  .+?               # 0 or more any character, not greedy
  <a href="/en/     # literally
  (.*?)             # group 1, 0 or more any character, not greedy
  ">                # literally
)                   # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: nice work, thanks Toto. Please add a two `//` after `https:` . I also edit the https: on my link

Answer (score 0):

For a simple scenario, such as:

```
   <link rel="canonical" href="link-one.html" />

   <a href="/en/link-two.html">
```

(check `.Matches newline`)

FIND: `(<link rel="canonical" href=").*?(" \/>)(.*?)(<a href="/en/(.*?)">)`

Replace by: `\1\5\2\3\4`

---

For a second scenario, such as:

```
   <link rel="canonical" href="https:/mywebsite.com//link-one.html" />

   <a href="/en/link-two.html">
```

(check `.Matches newline`)

FIND: `(<link rel="canonical" href=").*?(" \/>)(.*?)(<a href="/en/(.*?)">)`

Replace by: `\1https://mywebsite.com/\5\2\3\4`